# Angular application analytics measuring using Angulartics2 custom provider

Tags: angular, angulartics, angulartics2

We want to track URL changes and different events in our Angular (v5.1) application.

We need to receive the collected data to our own server, and not to one of the supported providers (like Google Analytics).

It seems that Angulartics2 supports a lot of providers and also have the ability for writing a custom provider. As they write in their website: "If there's no Angulartics2 plugin for your analytics vendor of choice, please feel free to write yours".

I don't find any documentation for how to write a custom provider. If anyone has any experience with that.

Or any recommendation for another analytics library that works with Angular and can send data to a custom URL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

same Question here... found Solution to share:
(First Stackoverflow contribution, excuse form issues)

1. Look at existing Providers

I've looked at [this one](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/blob/master/src/lib/providers/kissmetrics/kissmetrics.ts) cause its quite simple.

2. Rename it to fit your needs
3. Remove strange `declare var _kmq: any;` and inject your own ApiService instead.
4. Track your Stuff

I've removed `this.angulartics2.setUsername` and `this.angulartics2.setUserProperties` from constructor. Cause I don't know what it is used for...
My backend Team provided an endpoint which awaits following data structure:

```
export interface AnalyticsDataInterface {
    id?: number;
    userId: number;
    action: AnalyticsAction|string;
    properties: string[];
    date: string;
}
```

My Analytics Actions so far:

```
export enum AnalyticsAction {
    PAGE_VIEW = 'page_view',
    LOGIN = 'login_success',
}
```

Then this would be my ApiService:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AnalyticsService extends ApiService{

    public sendData(data: AnalyticsDataInterface){
        this.post<AnalyticsDataInterface>(Endpoint.ANALYTICS, data).subscribe();
    }
}
```

And last but not least my CustomProvider:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AngularticsProvider {

    constructor(
        private angulartics2: Angulartics2,
        private api: AnalyticsService,
        private userService: UserService
    ) {
        // this.angulartics2.setUsername
        //     .subscribe((x: string) => this.setUsername(x));
        // this.angulartics2.setUserProperties
        //     .subscribe((x) => this.setUserProperties(x));
    }

    startTracking(): void {
        this.angulartics2.pageTrack
            .pipe(this.angulartics2.filterDeveloperMode())
            .subscribe((x) => this.pageTrack(x.path));

        this.angulartics2.eventTrack
            .pipe(this.angulartics2.filterDeveloperMode())
            .subscribe((x) => this.eventTrack(x.action, x.properties));
    }

    pageTrack(path: string) {
        const requestData: AnalyticsDataInterface = {
            userId: this.userService.getUser().id,
            action: AnalyticsAction.PAGE_VIEW,
            properties: [path],
            date: new Date().toISOString()
        };

        this.api.sendData(requestData);
    }

    eventTrack(action: string, properties: string[]) {
        const requestData: AnalyticsDataInterface = {
            userId: this.userService.getUser().id,
            action,
            properties,
            date: new Date().toISOString()
        };
        this.api.sendData(requestData);
    }
}
```

Then just follow normal installation instructions

- import Angulartic2Module to AppModule:

  ```
    imports: [
        ...
        Angulartics2Module.forRoot(),
        ...
    ]
  ```
- inject your custom provider service to AppComponent and start tracking:

  ```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

        constructor(
            private myCustomProvider: AngularticsProvider
        ) {
            myCustomProvider.startTracking();
        }
    }
  ```

The rest should be default...